# C: union members become corrupted when compiled

Tags: c

Here's a C code that prints out the member information to the console.

```
#include "learnc0006.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

union Member {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int height;
};

void printMember(union Member data);

int learnc0006() {
    union Member data;

    strcpy(data.name, "Rico Angeloni");
    data.age = 30;
    data.height = 175;

    printMember(data);
    return 0;
}

void printMember(union Member data) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", data.name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", data.age);
    printf("Height: %d\n", data.height);
}
```

I expected that there would be no problem, but it showed a little bit different result, printing out a strange looking value for the name instead of showing the proper one.

```
Name: \257
Age: 175
Height: 175
```

Any good solutions will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you want a **struct**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be confusing struct with union. In a union, the element share the memory.

That means that when you write to the `age` field of your union, you are at the same time overwriting contents of `height` and `name`, which is not what you intend. The same holds when you write to `height`, where you write last. You can observe that pretty well, because in the end `age` is the same value as `height` and the first character of `name` is in fact the character number 175 (displayed as escaped octal `\257`).

Try to use `struct` instead of `union`.

Comment: Oh well! Thank you for the great tip :)